# FLUTTER : Displaying a loading indicator while listview.builder is building

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous

When clicking on an OPEN LIST button, the app creates a series of lists needed for future display. I found out that when the number of items in the list increases, these calculations can take a little time (2, 3 seconds). So for better UX, I would like to add something similar to a loading indicator telling the user the "lists are being prepared".
In my app, I use the package Loading Indicator : it works fine.
So I wanted to use it for this situation.
Here's what I did :

1. I transformed my "void" list creating functions into "Future Void".
2. I added the async keyword to the function plugged to my "OPEN LIST BUTTON".

But... for some reason, it never displays the loading indicator....

Here's the code (UI part) :

```
 onMenuOuvrir: () async {
                      DialogBuilder(context).showLoadingIndicator(
                          text: 'Ouverture de la liste', color: Colors.black45);

                      uD.setSelectedCarnetList(
                          index, uD.userInfo!.carnetList![index].ref!);
                      await uD.getListReady();
                      DialogBuilder(context).hideOpenDialog();
                      Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(
                          context, EditCarnetScreen.id);
                    },
```

Here's the code (Provider / back end part) :

```
 Future<void> getListReady() async {
    await createBufferCarnetWordBank();
    await createBufferCarnetList();
    await createBufferGrammarList();
    await createBufferLevelList();
    setEditMode(false);
    clearSearchList();
  }
```

The functions "createBuffer...List" are all of type Future .

What am I doing wrong ?

I actually found out that the problem was elsewhere... not in the creation of the lists, but in the building of the "listview.builder" in the EditCarnetScreen.

So here's the question now... how can we display some kind of indicator while this task is being processed.... it seems to be "in between screens"...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FutureBuilder` widget for that, e.g.

```
FutureBuilder(future: Provider.of<//your provider>(context)getListReady(), builder: (context, snapshot) => snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()) : //your widget)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it doesn't seem to work either. Am starting to wonder if we can use ASYNC with calculating functions, not involving APIs, downloading, uploading etc....

Answer (score 0):

Create a widget in a separate dart file :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
Loading(BuildContext context) {
return showDialog(
  context: context,
  barrierDismissible: false,
  builder: (BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: CircularProgressIndicator(
        valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.blue),
      ),
    );
  });
 }
```

Then use it anywhere in your code:

```
 Loading(context)
```

Dismiss in whenever you want:

```
Navigator.of(context).pop()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you process the calculation in the main thread, even if the indicator shows up the UI freezes and the spinning animation would be laggy.

You may process the heavy lifting tasks by `Isolate`s. Search for `Isolate` or `compute` method of dart.

Comment: Thanks :) I actually found out that the problem was coming from elsewhere.... can you look at the edited version of the question ?

Comment: Can you show your `listview.builder` function? it should not take more than fractions of a second.

Answer (score -1):

I have used the fluttertoast: ^8.0.8 package as shown below. You can set the toast length to a longer duration if needed. FutureBuilder is not useful in the case, where your widget themselves take a long time render. FutureBuilder is useful while fetching the data required for your widgets.

```
@override

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Fluttertoast.showToast(
      msg: 'Loading...'
    );
    //Code for your complex widget here
  }
```